# SQL server query by ranking and grouping based upon conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-partitioning

I am attempting to create a SQL query that will rank records  based upon  date created and then group by incidentId in table that logs interaction (request and then response)

A date calculation will be derived from then response date created - request date created,  but it is possible to have multiple instances of responses and requests

1. Request
2. Response - DateDiff between response (2) and request (1)
3. Request for more details
4. Response - DateDiff between response (4) and request (3)

I have managed to do the first part which is to identify and rank incidents, but unable to work out how to then group; see below the query and the resultset:

```
WITH rows
AS (
    SELECT ID,
        IncidentId,
        Cust,
        Channel,
        TTypeID,
        DateCreated,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY Id) AS 'rownum',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IncidentId ORDER BY DateCreated) AS Counts
    FROM [dbo].[Thread]
    WHERE TypeId IN (3, 4, 2, 1)
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ID,
        a.incidentId,
        a.Channel,
        a.rownum,
        a.TypeID,
        a.datecreated
    FROM rows a
    JOIN rows b
        ON a.incidentId = b.incidentId
    WHERE a.TypeId IN (3, 4, 2)
    ) AS base



 ID Incident           Channel          Rownum  Type    DateCreated
 24108571   9436560     Form            1       3           2015-04-22 13:41:29.000
 24109189   9436560     E-mail          2       2           2015-04-22 13:48:21.000
 24109788   9436560     Form            3       3           2015-04-22 13:49:39.000
 24109789   9436560     Email           4       2           2015-04-22 13:50:37.000
```

I would like to be able to rank the results again, so as to identify the number of request-responses.

The output should be as follows:

```
   ID       Incident           Channel      Rownum      Type                DateCreated             WaitTimeGrouping
 24108571   9436560         Form            1       3           2015-04-22 13:41:29.000             0
 24109189   9436560         E-mail          2       2           2015-04-22 13:48:21.000             1
 24109788   9436560         Form            3       3           2015-04-22 13:49:39.000                0
 24109789   9436560         Email           4       2           2015-04-22 13:50:37.000             2
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: If you want to return single row for each `Incident`, you will need to use some kind of aggregation function for other columns.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding more than 25% of what you're asking. Could you clarify? -- In the mean time, I assume that what you need is to join the `Thread` table to itself to find associated response and request records, and from there on calculate request-response-dependent data, and finally group/sort by that data.

Comment: SQL 2014. Updated to provide clarification.

Answer (score 0):

An example select to get you started may look like this:

```
SELECT
    req.Incident,
    MAX( resp.DateCreated - req.DateCreated ),
    MIN( resp.DateCreated - req.DateCreated ),
    AVG( resp.DateCreated - req.DateCreated )
FROM Thread req
INNER JOIN Thread resp
    ON req.Incident = resp.Incident
    AND resp.Rownum = req.RowNum+1
WHERE req.Type = 3 -- "Request"?
AND resp.Type = 2 -- "Response"?
GROUP BY req.Incident
```

Notice that we simply assume that the response's `Rownum` is always the request's `Rownum`+1. If this cannot be assured, another (sub-)query is required to find the match between a request and a response record.